# Number to String Value in php

Tags: php

I am asking a ridiculous question here:

Do we have any function in php that will convert number to string, for example

```
$i = 9;
$str = SOME_FUNCTION($i);
echo $str;
```

The above code will result: `NINE`

Similarly for $i=0 to 9;

It is different because I am clearly asking for PHP function and only for 0 to 9 numbers!

Comment: You can type cast in PHP `(int) $i`, or `(string) $i`

Comment: PHP doesn't have built-in function for that

Comment: Check this link http://pageconfig.com/post/number-to-word-conversion-with-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy.

```
$cypher = array('zero','one','two','three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine');
$i = 9;
echo $cypher[$i];
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP doesn't have a function that converts a number into a word.

You need to create a custom function. See the link below.

http://www.karlrixon.co.uk/writing/convert-numbers-to-words-with-php/